# What does "It's Mandarin for purgatory" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The phrase is taken from a TV series called "Arrow".
In the beginning of the first episode Oliver says: "The name of the island they found me on is Lian Yu. It's Mandarin for purgatory."

I've never seen a sentence like this one and don't even know how to google it.

Comment: [煉獄 in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%85%89%E7%8D%84)

Comment: We may have our first question there that is *about* the grammar that may be used for asking single word requests, but isn't a single word request. :)

Comment: Hm I closed based on belonging on ELL, but it gives the "not enough focus" message which frankly I don't understand why Cascabel and Edwin would have chosen that close reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"It's Mandarin for Purgatory" = "in the Mandarin language the name Lian Yu means purgatory".

Mandarin is one of the Chinese languages.
Purgatory is a place where the souls of the dead are purified (by pain) before they go to heaven, in Catholic teachings.

"X is the foreign language word for Y" is a common construction, and [Lian Yu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%85%89%E7%8D%84)  literally means purgatory in Mandarin. It's a way of conveying that the island is not a nice place.

Comment: liànyù literally means purgatory in Mandarin

Comment: @Henry though, note that it would work just fine as a semi-humorous statement even if it weren't literally accurate.